# Conditional Cabal Build Flag Failing

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have set the following structure in my project's cabal file:

```
library
  if flag(no-tracking)
    hs-source-dirs: src, no-telemetry
  else
    hs-source-dirs: src, telemetry
```

But I get "can't find source for " errors. I have verified that both `hs-source-dirs: src, telemetry` and `hs-source-dirs: src, no-telemetry` work without the conditional structure. It case it matters I am building with stack.